# ETags and 304 Not Modified response in grpc REST gateway

Tags: rest, go, grpc

I am auto-generating a REST API from a gRPC spec using the [grpc-gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway) project from Github. In this REST API, I'd like to support `ETag` headers and 304 Not Modified responses.

As far as I understand, normally you would create a response in the gRPC server with a specific status code, and that status code will then get translated into an HTTP status code by the grpc-gateway. However, since standard gRPC doesn't really support caching concepts, there is no gRPC status code that maps to the HTTP 304 status code.

Using grpc-gateway, it seems to be possible to customise HTTP status codes whenever the gRPC status code is en error code (overwriting the runtime.HTTPError function). However, I haven't found any way to customise the HTTP response code when the gRPC repsonse code is OK.

So, are there any recommended ways of achieving this?

Comment: im interested in this as well. here are some related issues i found looking through the github repo: https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/240 & https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/517

Comment: related google groups discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/1TJspS7QRwU quote
`I would say that this [caching] isn't really something we would like to introduce in the core of grpc. It is indeed left as an exercise to the reader in the sense that it is rather something that you would implement in your messages.

Not all kinds of rpc would find that feature relevant, so let's not make all of them pay its cost on the critical path. Authentication on the other hand is on the channel itself, and the presence of the code won't impact non-authenticated channels.`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to implement basic etag and 304 responses using a custom forwarder.

You can refer to these [directions](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/wiki/How-to-customize-your-gateway#replace-a-response-forwarder-per-method) to get setup, then implement the method along the lines of:

```golang
func forwardGetPost(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, resp proto.Message, opts ...func(context.Context, http.ResponseWriter, proto.Message) error) {
    // add cache-control rules for this proxy endpoint
    w.Header().Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=60")

    // create an etag
    // (when the response represents some entity from the db it may have a last edited timestamp)
    p := resp.(*Post)
    etag := fmt.Sprintf("W/%q", p.GetLastEdited())
    w.Header().Add("ETag", etag)

    // check whether the request provides an etag
    inm := req.Header.Get("If-None-Match")
    if inm != "" {
        if inm == etag {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotModified)
        }
    }
    runtime.ForwardResponseMessage(ctx, mux, marshaler, w, req, resp, opts...)
}
```

This does not prevent the proxy from making a request to the grpc server, but it will prevent sending those bytes back to the client when etags match.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! I guess your suggestion would work for GET requests with If-None-Match header. It does however seem to require that there is some property in the entity that can act as an ETag (in your example, "LastEdited"), which might not always be the case. A related problem is also how to handle POST/PUT requests with an "If-Match" header, where the If-Match header would need to be forwarded through gRPC somehow.

Comment: Yes good observations, I've been trying to figure out those cases also. Regarding Etags, some people will use an md5/sha1 hash of the whole response. So the forwarder would not need to know the type of the response or depend on any response fields to create the Etag. The trade-off is that is more cpu intensive to create hashes.